# How can I improve my Stack Overflow profile from an employers perspective?

Tags: discussion, jobs, profile-page

I have started to look into Stack Overflow Careers as way of finding available jobs in my area. Is there anything I can do to improve my [Stack Overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/509663/dunhamzzz) for an employer? At the moment my top-scoring answers aren't really an indication of my programming knowledge ([pointing out jQuery is a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062775/is-jquery-a-javascript-library-or-framework/7062787#7062787) is currently my highest). Is there anything I can do to improve the look of this?

Should I go through and delete dumb questions (like this one)? Unaccepted answers, etc.?

*Can any employers who used Stack Overflow Careers let us know what they looked for in a profile?*

Comment: Go through and change the order of your answers on the CV, leave out the snarky "Use the library. Done." type answers at least.

Comment: And get a serious user name, man!

Comment: And change your avatar.  It's the first thing people see when you visit your profile.

Comment: @Eat awwww probably a good idea, but I've had it for so long!

Comment: @Dunham I wasn't being entirely serious, look at my own user name :)

Comment: @Jay good idea, hilariously it got printed on my CakeFest ticket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your Stack Overflow profile itself is just fine and don't see anything there that is counter-indicative of good quality. In fact, quite the opposite: you have lots of well written content, lots of accepted answers and nothing hanging out there with any number of negative votes. Also, your level of participation (and therefore reputation score too) are well, well above the average Stack Overflow user, which certainly doesn't hurt.

Relative to how prospective employers view your profile, this is why the Careers Profiles are there -> to give *you* the ability to decide what *you* want to feature on *your* profile (or not). To your point, your highest voted and most popular content on Stack Overflow, while there is nothing wrong with it, may not be the same stuff you want to highlight to represent you. In this case, just go into your Careers profile and select the stuff you *do* want highlight.

In fact, the whole idea behind Stack Overflow Careers profiles is to give developers a specific place and a standard set of tools to curate all their contributions and accomplishments, precisely so that they can be showcased and searchable by prospective employers in the manner you determine.